# Cannot assign "default_connection" value to Tortoise ORM model with asyncpg driver?

Tags: python, tortoise-orm

I'm writing a plugin-based system in my application that loads Tortoise-ORM (`tortoise-orm = {extras = ["asyncpg"], version = "^0.19.3"}` ) models on demand.  I've written a very simple test one, below, with some basic fields.

```py
class PingModel(Model):
    uid = fields.TextField()
    ping_count = fields.IntField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

This being said, if I use `sqlite` as my Tortoise-ORM database, all works well.  However, if I create configuration like the following for `postgres`, I get an error when attempting to use the Model:

```py
        elif 'postgres' in self.config['database']:
            db_config = {
                'connections': {
                    'default': {
                        'engine': "tortoise.backends.asyncpg",
                        'credentials': {
                            'host': self.config['database']['postgres']['db_url'],
                            'port': self.config['database']['postgres']['db_port'],
                            'user': self.config['database']['postgres']['db_user'],
                            'password': self.config['database']['postgres']['db_password'],
                            'database': self.config['database']['postgres']['db_name'],
                        },
                    },
                },
                'apps': {
                    'models': {
                        'models': self.models,
                        'default_connection': 'default'
                    },
                },
            }
[...]
        await Tortoise.init(config=db_config)
        await Tortoise.generate_schemas()
```

And the exception I get when using it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tunacado/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/fishbot-5Nu9GTXz-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/commands/core.py", line 124, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(arg)
  File "/home/tunacado/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/fishbot-5Nu9GTXz-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/commands/core.py", line 978, in _invoke
    await self.callback(self.cog, ctx, **kwargs)
  File "/home/tunacado/Source/fishbot/fishbot/cogs/ping.py", line 17, in ping
    record = await PingModel.filter(uid__contains=user)
  File "/home/tunacado/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/fishbot-5Nu9GTXz-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tortoise/models.py", line 1255, in filter
    return cls._meta.manager.get_queryset().filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/tunacado/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/fishbot-5Nu9GTXz-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tortoise/manager.py", line 15, in get_queryset
    return QuerySet(self._model)
  File "/home/tunacado/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/fishbot-5Nu9GTXz-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tortoise/queryset.py", line 299, in __init__
    super().__init__(model)
  File "/home/tunacado/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/fishbot-5Nu9GTXz-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tortoise/queryset.py", line 96, in __init__
    self.capabilities: Capabilities = model._meta.db.capabilities
  File "/home/tunacado/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/fishbot-5Nu9GTXz-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tortoise/models.py", line 285, in db
    raise ConfigurationError(
tortoise.exceptions.ConfigurationError: default_connection for the model <class 'fishbot.cogs.ping.PingModel'> cannot be None
```

Just to note, I have ensured that we are in fact using this form of `db_config` and this isn't a logic error in my conditionals.  The `db_config` looks like this when I pass it to `init`:

```py
{'connections': {'default': {'engine': 'tortoise.backends.asyncpg', 'credentials': {'host': 'localhost', 'port': 5432, 'user': 'myuser', 'password': 'mypassword', 'database': 'mydb'}}}, 'apps': {'models': {'models': ['fishbot.cogs.ping'], 'default_connection': 'default'}}}
```

After research, I note that the Model itself *must* have an attribute of `Model._meta.default_connection` set to the connection name (`default`, in my case).  This is what this [GitHub issue describes](https://github.com/tortoise/tortoise-orm/issues/1188).  I even tried setting `class Meta` in my Model, and manually changing the `_meta.default_connection` model value and none of that seemed to work, same exact exception.

My question is why my Model never inherits the `default_connection` assigned in the configuration.  If we check the `self.models` in the above `apps:models` part of `db_config` it shows up as `fishbot.cog.ping`, which is the module that *contains* the `PingModel` Model I've built.  I can't import the model itself in the `models` section either; `fishbot.cogs.ping.PingModel` as the `models:models` section doesn't work either with `tortoise.exceptions.ConfigurationError: Module "fishbot.cogs.ping.PingModel" not found`.

Even if I hard-code it to `'models': ['fishbot.cogs.ping'],` I get the exact same exception; no matter what I can't get `default_connection` to stick to my models I import this way.

So that leaves me with my questions:

- Why isn't my model inheriting the `default_connection` from the configuration I placed?
- What is the proper way to ensure that I am setting `default_connection` on all of my models with initializing a `postgres` database with Tortoise-ORM?

Any advice is appreciated, including telling me what I messed up.

#### EDIT 0

So I ran the `postgres.py` in the [Tortoise example section](https://github.com/tortoise/tortoise-orm/blob/develop/examples/postgres.py) in my same `poetry` environment and it worked; it has to be specific to how my models are being passed in then...

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out eventually; I was *importing* my `PingModel` later on in code, which zeroed out the `default_connection` values I was specifying when intializing the database.

So now I need to work around imports for now; make sure you do not re-import after the `init` of Tortoise or the reference to the model you're trying to import may not be the one you expect.

Comment: Can you give any more details, this error is confusing the absolute buggery out of me.

Answer (score 0):

Another way this error can occur is if you import Tortoise models into one process, then create another process and try to use those models in the first one. This can also happen when you run `uvicorn` from code using `uvicorn.run`, without being careful.

To avoid this issue, it's best to ensure that the code which uses Tortoise models is not executed when preparing for `uvicorn.run`. Instead, `uvicorn` should import modelu that imports and initialize the Tortoise models, by setting `app="file"`. It's important to note that the file specified should not import the code that runs `uvicorn.run`, and vice versa: the code that runs `uvicorn.run` should not import the models.